# VBA Using a variable to select a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to code a system where I Select data from a set of worksheets whose titles are generated by the user. The Titles of the created sheets are then stored as strings. Is there a way to open/refer to a worksheet using these strings?

My code is as below

```
Dim Title As String
Dim Sheet_title As Worksheet

    Sheets("Config").Select
    Sheets("config").range("C25").Select
 
    Title = ActiveCell.Value
    Debug.Print Title
    Sheet_title = Title
    Sheets("Results").range("B7") = Sheets(title).range("E8")
```

The "sheets(Title)" fails, as well as my attempt to fix it by setting Sheet_Title = Title (Object variable not set - Error 91).

Is there any way to select a worksheet using a string variable?

Comment: **How** does `Sheets(Title)` fail? If it's error 9, then the sheet name is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Referencing Objects (`Set`)

**A Quick Fix**

- To reference a worksheet (any object), you need to use the *Set* keyword:

  ```
  Set Sheet_title = Sheets(Title)
  Sheets("Results").Range("B7").Value = Sheet_title.Range("E8").Value
  ```

**A Recommendation**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsCon As Worksheet: Set wsCon = wb.Sheets("Config")

    Dim Title As String: Title = wsCon.Range("C25").Value
    Debug.Print Title
    
    Dim wsTit As Worksheet: Set wsTit = wb.Sheets(Title)
    
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet: Set wsRes = wb.Sheets("Results")
    
    wsRes.Range("B7").Value = wsTit.Range("E8").Value

End Sub
```